# is there a way to reduce ram memory consumption for my python code

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, kaggle

I am trying to deploy a deep learning code for human action recognition on kaggle platform and I came across a ram memory shortage problem caused by this part of my code which is reading the frames of mp4 files of a dataset (350 files with fine resolution and 30 fps) :

```
data = []
labls = []
I for i,item in enumerate(tqdm(names)):
  print(names[i])
  imgs = get_frames(names[i])
  for j in imgs:
    data.append(j)
    labls.append(labels[i])
```

and

```
def get_frames(fileFullPath):

# Declare a list to store video frames.
images = []

video_reader = cv2.VideoCapture(fileFullPath)

#Get the total number of frames in the video.
video_frames_count = int(video_reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = min(int(video_frames_count * SEQUENCE_Ratio), 25)
# Calculate the the interval after which frames will be added to the list.
skip_frames_window = max((video_frames_count/SEQUENCE_LENGTH), 1)

frame_counter= 0
print(" Fetched frames=",SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

while frame_counter < SEQUENCE_LENGTH:
     # Print the percentage-progress.
        print_progress(count=frame_counter, max_count=SEQUENCE_LENGTH - 1)
        int(frame_counter * skip_frames_window) , "Seq=" , SEQUENCE_LENGTH )
        # Set the current frame position of the video.
        video_reader.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, int(frame_counter * skip_frames_window))
        success,image = video_reader.read()
        RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # resizing frames to (224 * 224)
        res = cv2.resize(RGB_img, dsize=(IMAGE_HEIGHT_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT_WIDTH),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        # Normalize the resized frame by dividing it with 255 so that each pixel value then lies between 0 and 1
        normalized_frame = res / 255
        images.append(normalized_frame)
        frame_counter += 1
   
# Release the VideoCapture object. 
video_reader.release()

# Return the frames list.
return images
```

i lowered the number of frames as much as to 25 frames per a file (not second)  and yet the 13 GB provided by Kaggle is not enough. And to make the problem even worse, next i have to convert the arrays into numpy array which also takes a lot of memory :

```
# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays
data = np.array(data)
labls = np.array(labls)
print ('number of frames will use to train and test the module is ',len(data))
```

any suggestion would be appreciated ,thanks.

Comment: What is the value of IMAGE_HEIGHT_WIDTH?

Comment: resizing dimensions 224 * 224

Comment: It seems like you are loading the full dataset into memory, you could build a data pipeline, where one batch of data is loaded, preprocessed and then passed to the model. The next batch gets prepared like this, while your model is updated, This way you use much less of your RAM. For TensorFlow, you could use the [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) package, which does all of the heavy lifting for you :) (An [alternative for PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) also exists)

Comment: thanks , i will look into that. Does this mean for instance the first batch of frames will be preprocessed and split into (train and testing)  groups and finally train the model for number of epochs and after all that the second batch enter the pipe line?

Comment: You would split the files into train/validation, then iterate the training set, as follows: 1) Read 1 batch, 2) prepare that batch (e.g. normalize, scale, crop, ...), 3) update model with that batch. Repeat until every sample from the trainset has been used. Do the same to validate your model. Iterate train and validation set for the number of training epochs. This works even better when you use multiprocessing. Maybe the Figures [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#optimized) help.

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not fit into your RAM, use a data pipeline. It works like this:

1. Read a single batch of data from disk into memory
2. Process that batch (e.g. normalize/scale/crop/...)
3. Feed that batch to the model and perform optimization step
4. Repeat from 1. until all samples in the dataset have been used.

Apply the steps for the training set first to run training for one epoch. After that you can iterate your validation set in the same way and subsequently continue with the second training epoch.

If you train your model using a GPU, the data loading and preprocessing can be handled by the CPU during the time it takes for the GPU to complete the optimization step. This provides a massive speed up as well.

There are packages in PyTorch and Tensorflow to make this really easy and even apply multiprocessing to speed up the whole routine.
Check [this guide by tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) for the basics and [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance) to optimize the pipeline.
PyTorch has something similar [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)